# Add value to image React Native

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, touchableopacity

I'm working on a project where you can pick a color. One color is one image. When a user selects an image (color) I need to get the value from that image.
As an example:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.onPress("I want to pass the color value")}>
<Image
    value={'I want this image to have a value, for instance Brown'}
    style={styles.image}
    source={require('../../assets/images/brown.png')}
/></TouchableHighlight>
```

In the example you can see what I mean. I also thought about making an array with the url to the image and the color as a name so you can get the values with a map, but I don't know how I can do that because I'm new to React Native.

```
const state = {quickReplies: ['test', 'test1']};

{this.state.quickReplies.map(reply =>
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by set state

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.setState({selectedColor:'brown'})}}>
            <Image
                value={'I want this image to have a value, for instance Brown'}
                style={styles.image}
                source={require('../../assets/images/brown.png')}
            /></TouchableHighlight>
```

or you can call a function in onPress Method

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.doSomething('brown')}}>
            <Image
                value={'I want this image to have a value, for instance Brown'}
                style={styles.image}
                source={require('../../assets/images/brown.png')}
            /></TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imgs: [
        { url: '../../assets/images/brown.png', color: '#887766' },
        { url: '...', color: '...' },
        { url: '...', color: '...' },
      ],
    };
  }

  doSomething = ({ color, index }) => {
    // Access the rest of your img details:
    const imgDetails = this.state.imgs[index];
  };

  render() {
    const { imgs } = this.state;

    return imgs.map(({ url, color }, index) => (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.doSomething({ color, index })}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: url }} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation... have an active color in your state, set state to that active color, and then the source for the image would be

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.setState(activeColor: 'brown')}}>
  <Image
   style={styles.image}
   source={require(`../../assets/images/${this.state.color}.png`)}
  />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Just make sure u set the initial state with an active color so nothing breaks